# How are weights organized in Conv2D layers?

Tags: keras, cnn

I trained a model using Keras from this [example](https://keras.io/examples/mnist_cnn/). The model summary showed me this result

```
    Model: "sequential_1"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 26, 26, 32)        320       
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)            (None, 24, 24, 64)        18496     
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2 (None, 12, 12, 64)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)          (None, 12, 12, 64)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_1 (Flatten)          (None, 9216)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 128)               1179776   
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_2 (Dropout)          (None, 128)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 10)                1290      
=================================================================
Total params: 1,199,882
Trainable params: 1,199,882
Non-trainable params: 0
```

There are 8 layers and `model.get_weights()` also shows the first dimension of 8. As I understood correctly things like Pooling and Flatten are "operators" over the input matrices, so why it is presented as a layer? How to understand what is stored in weight array for example in Pooling layer (`model.get_weights()[2]`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you print those shapes using below for loop

```
weights_m=model.get_weights()
for i in range(8):
  print(weights_m[i].shape)
```

you will get output as

(3, 3, 1, 32)
(32,)
(3, 3, 32, 64)
(64,)
(9216, 128)
(128,)
(128, 10)
(10,)

so we will get one layer weight and bias. we have a total of 4 layers(2 conv + 2 dense) so 8 weight vectors.

Comment: subarrays with only one dimension are biases?

Comment: Yes. Those 1d arrays are biases. For every layer, you are using bias so 4 laters, 4 bias vectors.

Comment: ok thx it's clear

Answer (score 0):

model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3),activation='relu',input_shape=input_shape))

```
3x3 weights + 1 bias for each feature map. It has 32 feature map.
This is first 2 lines. (3X3+1)X32. At this points feature size is 26X26(valid padding)
```

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))

```
3x3 weights connected to 32 previous feature maps + 1 bias for each feature map. It has 64 feature maps.
This is 3rd and 4th lines (3X3X32+1)X64. At this points feature size is 24X24(valid padding)
```

model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

```
At this points, feature size is 12X12(Pooling)
```

model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Flatten())

```
64 feature maps of size 12X12 are flattened. 144X64=9216 mapped to 128 neurons + 128 biases
This is 5th and 6th lines
```

model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))

```
128 neurons are mapped to 10 neurons + 10 biases
This is 7th and 8th lines
```

model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))

[how-to-calculate-the-number-of-parameters-of-convolutional-neural-networks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28232235/how-to-calculate-the-number-of-parameters-of-convolutional-neural-networks)